# Symfony2, Varnish and ESI lead to strange behavior

Tags: symfony, varnish, esi

I have the following config:

```
varnish (80) <-> nginx (8080) <-> php-fpm (9000)
```

(Same behavior using Apache with mod_php)
My Varnish config:

```
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "8080";
    .connect_timeout = 600s;
    .first_byte_timeout = 600s;
    .between_bytes_timeout = 600s;
}

sub vcl_recv {
    set req.http.Surrogate-Capability = "abc=ESI/1.0";
}


sub vcl_fetch {    
    if (beresp.http.Surrogate-Control ~ "ESI/1.0") {
        unset beresp.http.Surrogate-Control;
        set beresp.do_esi = true;
    }
}

sub vcl_deliver {
    if (obj.hits > 0) {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "HIT Varnish (" +obj.hits+ ")";
    } else {
        set resp.http.X-Varnish-Cache = "MISS";
    }
}
```

ESI is turned on in the `app/config/config.yml`. I configured the following routes in symfony:

- `/esiouter` with s-maxage 60 and having an esi-include for `/esiinner` (using "plain" esi-tag or twig-render function with `{'standalone': true}`): `<esi:include src="/esiinner" />`
- `/esiinner` with s-maxage 10 (fetched by esi-include)

Now when I enable the AppCache in `web/app.php` symfony evaluates the ESI tags so varnish doesn't get them and we have a `Content-Length` header and the content is not chunked. If I disable the AppCache, varnish evaluates the ESI tags and sends the content chunked and there is no `Content-Length` header.

Why is Varnish sending a chunked response and is not buffering the esi-blocks and sending the page as a whole?
If I am using Varnish infront of my Symfony-Application with ESI, do I have to use Symfonys AppCache?

Comment: I'll hopefully have time to investigate this later today, if you haven't solved it by yourself? I can at least tell you that you shouldn't use the AppCache, since this basically is a replacement for Varnish.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a software Gateway cache / Reverse proxy (like Varnish) you don't need to enable `AppCache` (which is the Symfony2 Reverse proxy written in PHP).

Letting `AppCache` enabled can leads to unconsistent behaviour because you would have 2 Reverse proxies.

Comment: The thing that bugs me is that the [Symfony documentation about caches](http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/http_cache.html#symfony-reverse-proxy) states: [...] _The good news is that the switch from one proxy server to another is easy and transparent as no code modification is needed in your application._ [...]. But removing `AppCache` in `app.php` _is_ a modification. Maybe this is nitpicking but I want to be sure that `AppCache` really is _just_ the reverse proxy of Symfony and nothing more.